# Foreach rodando só uma vez

Tags: php

Tenho um código que lê um txt e grava no banco os dados do txt, só que o foreach não faz a repetição e grava só a primeira linha.

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode('|', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);

$COD = $valor[1];
$NOME = $valor[2];
$CARACT = $valor[3];
$END = $valor[4];
$CPF = $valor[5];

$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES ('$COD','$NOME','$CARACT','$END','$CPF')";

$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);

}
```

Meu txt se encontra assim:

```
|42|Carlos Paiva da Silva|2|Av. Alameda Santos, 255|15265482536|
```

(não há só uma linha no arquivo, é só um exemplo)

Comment: João, poste o ao menos um exemplo do conteúdo do arquivo

Comment: @rbz Atualizei a pergunta com o conteúdo.

Comment: @JoãoMiguel iae, conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela *identação* o seu código deveria finalizar após o `var_dump`:

```
foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode('|', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);
```

Porém não tem o `}`; com isso, (possivelmente) o bloco é fechado no que seria o final do método. Adicione o *fechar chave*:

```
foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode('|', $linha);
    var_dump($valor);
}
```

---

**editado após comentários**

A variável `$valores` (após o `explode`) contém sua real lista de itens a serem inseridos. Alterei o nome da variável para ficar mais intuitivo, veja se resolve:

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valores = explode('|', $linha);
    var_dump($valores);

    foreach($valores as $valor){

        $COD = $valor[1];
        $NOME = $valor[2];
        $CARACT = $valor[3];
        $END = $valor[4];
        $CPF = $valor[5];

        $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES ('$COD','$NOME','$CARACT','$END','$CPF')";

        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    }
}
```

Uma alternativa seria criar uma *string* concatenando os valores e dar apenas um *insert*, já que o primeiro funciona (sim, isso é gambiarra):

```
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);
$result_usuario = "";

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valores = explode('|', $linha);
    var_dump($valores);

    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES";
    foreach($valores as $valor){    
        $COD = $valor[1];
        $NOME = $valor[2];
        $CARACT = $valor[3];
        $END = $valor[4];
        $CPF = $valor[5];

        $result_usuario .= "('$COD','$NOME','$CARACT','$END','$CPF'),";
    }

    $result_usuario = substr($result_usuario, 0, -1); 

    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
}
```

Comment: Assim o  código não finalizaria antes da inserção no banco de dados?

Comment: antes tava sem a última chave =p se você der um `count($dados)`, tem mais de um item pra inserir?

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido de adicionar na pergunta x) dei o     count e só resultou na primeira linha mesmo, porém no var_dump ele me retorna todas linhas!

Comment: então você precisa de um novo `foreach`, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: Ainda assim não funcionou :/

Comment: `var_dump($valor)` dentro do segundo `foreach` mostra valores corretos (entra mais de uma vez)? Se sim, não sei o que há de errado =/

Comment: Sim os valores estão sendo carregados, o problema deve ser na parte do SQL

Comment: se ele insere corretamente o primeiro, não entendo porque daria erro nos outros...

Comment: No primeiro código, se houver zilhões de linhas vai fazer zilhões de inserts. No segundo vai gerar isso `INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES('','','','',''),('2','','','',''),('a','r','l','o','s'),('','','','',''),('v','.',' ','A','l'),('5','2','6','5','4'),('','','','','')INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES('','','','',''),('3','','','',''),('a','r','l','o','s'),('','','','',''),('v','.',' ','A','l'),('5','2','6','5','4'),('','','','','')INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES ...............`

Comment: Tentei fazer desta forma, e nem chegou a salvar no banco.

Comment: agora o segundo código ficou correto! Nem vou testar pq ficou quase que igual ao meu.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Recebe os dados do formulario
$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

//ler todo o arquivo para um array
$dados = file($arquivo_tmp);

foreach($dados as $linha){
    $linha = trim($linha);
    $valor = explode('|', $linha);

   $COD = $valor[1];
   $NOME = $valor[2];
   $CARACT = $valor[3];
   $END = $valor[4];
   $CPF = $valor[5];

   //prepara os values
   $result_usuario .=  "('$COD','$NOME','$CARACT','$END','$CPF'),";

}

//retira a ultima virgula
$values=substr($result_usuario, 0, -1);

//a query para inserir os dados no banco

    //$conn = ......

    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES $values";

    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
```

**Tabela do banco**

[image: ia tabela]

**Arquivo txt**

[image: arquivo txt]

**Após rodar o código PHP**

[image: após rodar php]

> Uma única declaração INSERT ... VALUES pode adicionar múltiplos registros em uma tabela se você fornecer múltiplas listas de valores. Para fazer isso, forneça uma lista de valores entre parêntesis para cada registro e separe as listas com virgulas.

Por exemplo:

```
"INSERT INTO info (COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF) VALUES
('42','Carlos Paiva da Silva 2','2','Av. Alameda Santos, 2','5265482532'),('43','Carlos Paiva da Silva 3','3','Av. Alameda Santos, 3','5265482533'), etc...
```

A declaração mostrada cria registros na tabela info, atribuindo às colunas `COD, NOME, CARACT, END, CPF` de cada registro os valores listados. A coluna id (caso haja) não é listada explicitamente, de modo que o MySQL atribui um valor da sequência para essa coluna em cada registro.

Uma declaração INSERT de múltiplas linhas é logicamente equivalente a um conjunto de declarações de única linha individuais. Entretanto, a declaração de múltiplas linhas é mais eficiente porque o servidor pode processar todas as linhas de uma vez em vez de em operações separadas. Quando você tiver muitos registros a adicionar, declarações de múltiplas linhas fornecem um desempenho melhor e reduzem a carga do servidor.

Comment: Tentei fazer desta forma, e nem chegou a salvar no banco.

Comment: @JoãoMiguel, algo errado você fez. Veja minha resposta editada. Talvez você tenha esquecido da string de conexão ou executar a declaração INSERT